# Level Order Traversal of a binary tree(Refer code below for specific details of the question)

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

In the code below , why do I need this specific line :

```
ArrayList<Integer> c_curr = new ArrayList<Integer>(curr);
```

Why can't I just add curr to the result res ? When I try doing that , I get an empty res .

```
public List<List<Integer>> levelOrder(TreeNode root) {
    List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    if (root == null)
        return res;
    Queue<TreeNode> q = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
    q.add(root);
    q.add(null);
    ArrayList<Integer> curr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    TreeNode t;
    while (!q.isEmpty()) {
        t = q.poll();

        if (t != null) {
            curr.add(t.val);
            if (t.left != null) {
                q.offer(t.left);
            }
            if (t.right != null) {
                q.offer(t.right);
            }
        } else {
            ArrayList<Integer> c_curr = new ArrayList<Integer>(curr);
            res.add(c_curr);
            curr.clear();
            if (!q.isEmpty())
                q.offer(null);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose we change these lines like this:

```
//ArrayList<Integer> c_curr = new ArrayList<Integer>(curr);
//res.add(c_curr);
res.add(curr);
curr.clear();
```

The list `curr` added to result `res`. Java passes arguments by value. So when you call

```
boolean java.util.List.add(List<Integer> e)
```

method, the value of `curr` copied to `e`. But since `curr` is an object, `curr` and `e` refers to the same place in memory. So when you clear `curr`, you get an empty `res`.

That's because a new list `c_curr` is created with values of `curr`. Then added to `res` in the original code. Thus modifying curr doesn't affect res.